# How Do I take a Snapshot and Migrate Token Holders to a new ERC20 Contract?

Tags: remix, erc-20, cpp-ethereum

[image: Migrate a new Contract]

I want to Migrate my ERC20 Contract to a new Address, How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about it:

1. Get all the `Transfer`, `Mint`, and `Burn` events for your contract
2. Computer a user balance based on the credits and debits from the events for each address that holds your tokens
3. Deploy a new contract, and use some way to airdrop the required amounts to each holder of the old tokens

Alternatively, you can:

1. Deploy the new token contract with a mechanism that allows users to send the old tokens to the contract, and receive the new ones in return.